# Saving console output to an int array

Tags: c++, console

I want to run this command:

`wmic diskdrive get index`

and store the indexes in an `int` array.

Could you help me?

Comment: You forgot yo include what you tried to solve this problem.

Comment: Unless you are piping the output of the command to your program`s stdin, then this is an OS-specific problem, and you should probably elaborate on your environment a bit.

Comment: You probably want to look up [`_popen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen?view=msvc-170) about now. Given the command you're trying to run, I'm assuming Windows. On Linux or similar, you want [`popen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html). Once you've done that, you basically just read the output from a stream.

Comment: WMIC is a deprecated tool that is part of Windows. If you just want the index of your drives, why not use the Windows API to do it, rather than invoking an external tool?

Comment: You've wandered into [X-Y question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) territory. As hinted in the comment above, there are more direct tools to get what you seem to want, but to suggest the best option for your case, we need to know what problem led you to this potential solution.

Comment: I want to get info about hard disks using S.M.A.R.T. and I should use indexes for that.
P.S. I use Windows

Comment: Basically you're trying to execute the WMI query `SELECT Index FROM Win32_DiskDrive`. You can query WMI from a C++ application without invoking an external tool. See example [Getting WMI Data from the Local Computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--getting-wmi-data-from-the-local-computer) and documentation for the [Win32_DiskDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-diskdrive) class.

Answer (score 0):

I found this idea elsewhere on this site: try calling `CreateFile()` for all possible indexes of `"\\\\.\\PhysicalDriveN"`.

There are claims that Windows only support up to 16 physical drives, and that those indexes are sequential - you need to verify that. If there might be more - increase the limit. And if they ARE in fact sequential - you may break out of the loop after first `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

Here is what I got:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> indexes;

    for (int index = 0; index < 16; ++index) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive" << index;
        //std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
        HANDLE disk = CreateFileA(ss.str().c_str(),
            GENERIC_READ,
            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
            NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            NULL);
        if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == disk) {
            DWORD err = GetLastError();
            if (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED == err) {
                // No access - you need Admin rights to open this file
                // But the drive is there!
                //std::cout << "ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED" << std::endl;
                indexes.push_back(index);
            }
            else if (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND == err) {
                // No such drive
                //std::cout << "ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                // TODO: research - what else could've happened?
                std::cout << err << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else {
            indexes.push_back(index);
            CloseHandle(disk);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Found indexes:" << std::endl;
    for (auto index : indexes) {
        std::cout << index << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than looping through all *possible* indexes, it would be better to just ask Windows how many physical disks are actually present, and then loop through only that many disks.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That would be better (cleaner), certainly. I've listed two claims in my answer that I don't have a proof for. However, if they ARE correct - I did offer to `break out of the loop after first ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, so you don't even need a count.

Comment: sure, provided disk numbers are consecutive, and don't appear/disappear or get reassigned dynamically as drives are added and removed while Windows is running. I don't know how the disk numbers react in those situations.